# Regex in Sublime text 2

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I am using the following regex operation to get find some section of text -

```
\/\*\*((\n \*.*)*)\/\n((.*\n))*?\{
```

And then replacing it with the following pattern

```
\/\*\*$1\/\n$3\{\nprintk("**$1");\n
```

I am new to using regex and I want to remove the newline characters contained in $1, is this possible and if so how?

----Edit----

Example:

```
/**
 *  This is a multiline commment1
 *  This is a multiline commment2
 *  This is a multiline commment3
 **/
int fnName(struct a *b)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Current output is

```
/**
 *  This is a multiline commment1
 *  This is a multiline commment2
 *  This is a multiline commment3
 **/
int fnName(struct a *b)
{
printk("**
 *  This is a multiline commment1
 *  This is a multiline commment2
 *  This is a multiline commment3
 **");

    return 0;
}
```

Although I want output as

```
/**
 *  This is a multiline commment1
 *  This is a multiline commment2
 *  This is a multiline commment3
 **/
int fnName(struct a *b)
{
printk("** *  This is a multiline commment1 *  This is a multiline commment2 *  This is a multiline commment3 **");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of text that you are searching, your expected results, and the results you are getting now.

Comment: I have provided an example regarding my expected results and my current output, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't think Regular expressions cant do what you are asking. You cant transform the selected text in the replacement all in one go like you would like.

I would suggest using sublime texts multi-edit functionality to select, transform then paste what you need where you need it. Not as easy as what you are asking for but a solution.

For example:

- Do a multi find on all the comment blocks, and copy them
- Then paste them to a new file for transformation and wrapping with prinkk
- Then multi-line copy back and do a multi-line paste into the desired location